# Youtube v3 API origin parameter doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube

I've been having trouble using the origin parameter in Youtube's v3 API recently. Whenever I don't include it I'm able to play everything but Vevo-type videos that have restricted playback. When I try to play a Vevo video the video just says that playback is restricted.

Other answers online have said that adding an origin parameter set to https://www.example.com should allow Vevo videos to be played. However, when I do this and attempt to play a Vevo video, the video just goes black, and there isn't even a message saying that playback is restricted. Also, when I try to play regular videos by evaluating a Javascript command, nothing happens, and I'm forced to actually click on the videos to play them for some reason. If anybody knows how to play Vevo videos through Youtube's API, whether with the origin parameter or through some other method, I'd appreciate it.

Here is my HTML code for player:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="player" webkit-playsinline></div>
        <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
        <script>
            var player;
            YT.ready(function() {
                     player = new YT.Player('player', %@);
                     window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onYouTubeIframeAPIReady';
                     });
                     function onReady(event) {
                         window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onReady?data=' + event.data;
                     }
        function onStateChange(event) {
            window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onStateChange?data=' + event.data;
        }
        function onPlaybackQualityChange(event) {
            window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onPlaybackQualityChange?data=' + event.data;
        }
        function onPlayerError(event) {
            window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onError?data=' + event.data;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the code I'm using to initialize the player and to add it's parameters.

```
fileprivate func loadWebViewWithParameters(_ parameters: YouTubePlayerParameters) {

        // Get HTML from player file in bundle
        let rawHTMLString = htmlStringWithFilePath(playerHTMLPath())!

        // Get JSON serialized parameters string
        let jsonParameters = serializedJSON(parameters as AnyObject)!

        // Replace %@ in rawHTMLString with jsonParameters string
        let htmlString = rawHTMLString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%@", with: jsonParameters)

        // Load HTML in web view
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: URL(string: "about:blank"))
    }

    fileprivate func playerHTMLPath() -> String {
        return Bundle(for: self.classForCoder).path(forResource: "YTPlayer", ofType: "html")!
    }

    fileprivate func htmlStringWithFilePath(_ path: String) -> String? {

        do {

            // Get HTML string from path
            let htmlString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            return htmlString as String

        } catch _ {

            // Error fetching HTML
            printLog("Lookup error: no HTML file found for path")

            return nil
        }
    }


    // MARK: Player parameters and defaults

    fileprivate func playerParameters() -> YouTubePlayerParameters {
        playerVars["origin"] = ("https://www.example.com") as AnyObject?
        playerVars["playsinline"] = 1 as AnyObject?
        playerVars["controls"] = 0 as AnyObject?
        playerVars["showinfo"] = 0 as AnyObject?
        return [
            "modestbranding": 1 as AnyObject,
            "height": "100%" as AnyObject,
            "width": "100%" as AnyObject,
            "events": playerCallbacks() as AnyObject,
            "playerVars": playerVars as AnyObject
        ]
    }

    fileprivate func playerCallbacks() -> YouTubePlayerParameters {
        return [
            "onReady": "onReady" as AnyObject,
            "onStateChange": "onStateChange" as AnyObject,
            "onPlaybackQualityChange": "onPlaybackQualityChange" as AnyObject,
            "onError": "onPlayerError" as AnyObject
        ]
    }
```

Is there a domain other than example.com that I should try? Is there another issue at fault here? The Github where I got the code for the Youtube Player is https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player and the Swift 3 code can be found in the Issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://www.youtube.com/ as a baseURL parameter in loadHTMLString:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/"))
```

Then try to delete the origin param from your playerParameters func - this line:

```
playerVars["origin"] = ("https://www.example.com") as AnyObject?
```

It works like this for me.